# Quickcheck: produce arbitrary elements of an arbitrary set

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Suppose that I am writing tests for `Data.Set`. I would like to check that deleting elements from the set works, and so I might write something like this:

```
prop_deleteA it x = member x it ==> not (member x (delete x it))
```

assuming that `it` has a suitable `Arbitrary` instance. However, this relies on quickcheck generating values of `x` that happen to exist within the set, which is not in general guaranteed. It would be much better if `x` could be made to depend on `it` so as to guarantee that `x` is already a member of `it`. How might I do this?

I had the thought that I could write

```
prop_deleteB it f = let x = f it
                   in not (member x (delete x it))
```

where `f :: Set a -> a` is suitably defined by means of coarbitrary. However, coarbitrary would only allow us to define `f :: Set a -> b`, which unfortunately isn't what we want. My best thought so far has been to define a new type

```
data SetAndElement a = SetAndElement (Set a) a
```

which allows us to write a suitable `Arbitrary` instance

```
instance (Ord a, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (SetAndElement a) where
    arbitrary = do it <- suchThat arbitrary (not . Set.null)
                   x  <- elements (elems it)
                   return (SetAndElement it x)
```

allowing `prop_delete` to be written as

```
prop_deleteC (SetAndElement it x) = not (member x (delete x it))
```

This works, but seems a little involved; are there any better options? (If not, I'll modify the question and put this as an answer.) The actual `Data.Set` implementation (containers package) tests deletion by checking that `(delete x) . (insert x) == id` if `x` was not already a member of the given set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what generators you have available. For example, if you already have `setOf1` (generates a `Set` with at least one element) and `setElements` (takes elements from a `Set`), it can be written with `forAll`:

```
-- example implementations of both combinators
setOf1 :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen a -> Gen (Set a)
setOf1 = fmap fromList . listOf1

setElements :: Set a -> Gen a
setElements = elements . toList

prop_delete =
  forAll (setOf1 arbitrary)   $ \theSet ->
  forAll (setElements theSet) $ \x ->
    not (member (x :: Int) (delete x theSet))
```

This is mostly the same as `SetAndElement`, but instead of a fixed `data` type, we're using re-usable functions that can be used for further tests:

```
prop_null =  forAll (setOf1 (arbitrary :: Gen Integer)) $ not . null
```

However, even if you don't write `setOf1` or `setElements`, `forAll` can be rather succinct for simple tests:

```
prop_delete :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => (NonEmptyList a) -> Property
prop_delete (NonEmpty xs) =
  let theSet = fromList xs
  in forAll (elements xs) $ \x ->
      not (member x (delete x theSet))
```

If you provide `setElements` and `NonEmptySet`, this can be written as

```
newtype NonEmptySet x = NonEmptySet {getNonEmptySet :: Set a}

instance (Ord a, Arbitray a) => Arbitrary (NonEmptySet a) where
  arbitrary = fmap NonEmptySet . setOf1 $ arbitrary

prop_delete :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => (NonEmptySet a) -> Property
prop_delete (NonEmptySet theSet) =
  forAll (setElements theSet) $ \x ->
    not (member x (delete x theSet))
```

That way you can use `NonEmptySet` for tests that require a non-empty set, and `setElements` only for those where you actually need to choose an element at random.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I had previously encountered `forAll`, but hadn't properly appreciated it. My efforts were mostly misdirected towards a `coarbitrary` solution.